# Compiling Caffe with Cmake and Ninja fails

Tags: cmake, caffe, ninja

I tried compiling Caffe on windows with `CMAKE_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` option on, but it failed and stated I need to use Ninja. When I set Ninja to 1 in the config file (`build_win.cmd`), and run the script, it complains and gives the following error message:

```
 CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to
 "Ninja".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select
 a different build tool. CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after
 EnableLanguage CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after
 EnableLanguage
 -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! ERROR: Configure failed
```

I don't know what other steps I need to take in order to have a successful compilation process. All I did was to download Ninja, extract it somewhere and add it to my environment variable.

Do I need to install gcc as well?

### Update

As suggested in the comments, I checked my path and noticed it was ill-configured. I fixed that now I get these errors, it seems it can't find the needed libraries:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 6.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 6.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Users/Master/gcc/bin/gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Users/Master/gcc/bin/gcc.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Users/Master/gcc/bin/c++.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Users/Master/gcc/bin/c++.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Warning at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:744 (message):
  Imported targets not available for Boost version
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:848 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1435 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  cmake/Dependencies.cmake:8 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:79 (include)


CMake Warning at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:744 (message):
  Imported targets not available for Boost version
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:848 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1435 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  cmake/Dependencies.cmake:8 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:79 (include)


CMake Warning at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:744 (message):
  Imported targets not available for Boost version
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:848 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1435 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  cmake/Dependencies.cmake:8 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:79 (include)


-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - not found
-- Found Threads: TRUE
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1793 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Unable to find the Boost header files.  Please set BOOST_ROOT to the root
  directory containing Boost or BOOST_INCLUDEDIR to the directory containing
  Boost's headers.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Dependencies.cmake:8 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:79 (include)


-- Could NOT find GFlags (missing:  GFLAGS_INCLUDE_DIR GFLAGS_LIBRARY)
-- Could NOT find Glog (missing:  GLOG_INCLUDE_DIR GLOG_LIBRARY)
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:138 (message):
  Could NOT find Protobuf (missing: Protobuf_LIBRARIES Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindProtobuf.cmake:393 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  cmake/ProtoBuf.cmake:9 (find_package)
  cmake/Dependencies.cmake:48 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:79 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "G:/caffe_latest2/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "G:/caffe_latest2/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
ERROR: Configure failed
```

Comment: Make sure your Ninja path is set correctly. As the error message very clearly says - it can't find Ninja.

Comment: @tambre: Thanks, It was indeed wrong. I fixed that, now I get other errors! it cant find the dependencies !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause. I had installed GCC on my system, and `cmake` would try to use that instead of Visual C++ compiler.
All that is needed is just downloading Ninja, placing it in your Path Variable and you are good to go.
Change the needed settings in the `build_win.cmd` to use Ninja and you are done